# S3 TransferUtility throws "The file indicated by the FilePath property does not exist" error

Tags: c#, amazon-s3, azure-functions

I'm trying to upload a programmatically created file to my Amazon S3 bucket but I keep getting the following error:

> The file indicated by the FilePath property does not exist.

My app is an Azure Functions app but I get this error both locally and on Azure.

When I run it locally, I see that the file is actually there -- exactly as indicated by the file path. Locally, this path is `C:\Users\{MyUserName}\AppDate\Local\Temp\{MyFileName}.csv`.

Here's the method that handles uploading files to my S3 bucket. First, the constructor section that handles the `AmazonS3Client`:

```
private readonly AmazonS3Client _client;
private string _bucketName;

public S3Client(string accessKey, string secretKey, string bucketName)
{
   if(_client == null)
     _client = new AmazonS3Client(accessKey, secretKey, Amazon.RegionEndpoint.USEast1);

   _bucketName = bucketName;
}
```

And here's the method that handles uploading the file to S3:

```
public async Task UploadFileToS3(string filePath, string blobName)
{
   try
   {
      var fileTransferUtility = new TransferUtility(_client);

      await fileTransferUtility.UploadAsync(filePath, _bucketName, blobName);
   }
   catch (Exception e)
   {
      throw new Exception(e.Message);
   }
}
```

Any idea what may be causing this issue?

P.S. Here's the app specs

```
<TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
<AzureFunctionsVersion>v3</AzureFunctionsVersion>
```

Comment: How long is your CSV filename? I've encountered this error being thrown before for long file paths - try moving the file to somewhere with a shorter file path. Does that work?

Comment: You may also have the file on the disk but can your application read the file? Try doing a `File.ReadAllText` and seeing if that actually returns something to cross out concerns over file access from within the application (let's focus on fixing this locally first and then dealing with Azure app service).

Comment: Shortening the file name didn't help. I was, however, able to get a bit more info from the exception. Looks like it's looking in the wrong place for the file. I set the path for file with `System.IO.Path.GetTempPath() + "my-file-" + DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmm");` and this places the file in `C:\Users\sam\AppData\Local\Temp` folder. In the error message, I see that it's looking for it in the `bin` folder under the `Debug` folder where my app is running. I actually pass the path to the upload method so not sure why the paths are different.

Comment: Can you please add the full code to the question then please? I/we can then troubleshoot